# Multiplication of a Riesz basis

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, operator-theory, sp.spectral-theory, sobolev-spaces

Let ${(\phi_n(.),\psi_n(.))}_{n\geq 1}$ be a Riesz basis in $H^1_0(0,1) \times L^2(0,1)$.
My question is the following: If we multiply the basis by the matrix $e^{Mx}$, $x \in (0,1)$ where $M$ is a constant matrix of dimension $2$, is this still a Riesz basis?
I can prove that the operator $T: H^1_0(0,1) \times L^2(0,1) \rightarrow H^1_0(0,1) \times L^2(0,1)$ taking $(f,g)\rightarrow e^{Mx}(f,g)$ is bounded from above, but not from below.
Is this statement true?.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is $x$ here? A number? If so, then $T$ will not be an operator into $H^1_0(0,1) \times L^2(0,1)$ unless $x=0$ or the matrix $M$ is lower triangular.

Comment: I am surprised at what you can prove. Given an arbitrary pair $(\phi, \psi)\in H^0_1 \times L^2$, and consider the matrix valued function $e^{Mx}$. If you write $(\tilde{\phi}, \tilde{\psi})$ for $e^{Mx}(\phi, \psi)$, generally $\tilde{\phi}$ is not going to be vanishing on the boundary.

Comment: thank you. I can see it now.

Comment: And what if I consider the space $H^1_0(0,1)^2$ instead of $H^1_0(0,1)\times L^2(0,1)$?. I think that this is true. Please, correct me if I'm mistaken. Thank you.